# Не инициализируется структура Си

Tags: c, winapi, struct

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я просто инициализирую структуры к нулю внутри "мэйна" все в порядке всё работает.

Но когда когда этаже структура является вложенной в другую структуру, оно выдаёт ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если это делат даже не просто в структуре а в функции где я создаю объект даной структуры, всё еще выдаёт туже ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите чем это вызвано и как всё-таки привести вложенную структуру к нулю.

Comment: Не путайте си и с++. В си объявление структуры может только объявить ее.

Comment: @こきん почему тогда как показано на первых картинках оно не ругается и работает?

Comment: Потому что это не структура? Потому что включены расширения компилятора?

Comment: перед фигурными скобками нужно указать тип структуры. `... -> wc = (WNDCLASSEX) { 0 } ;`. Код программы пишите **текстом**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала поймите что си и с++ 2 разных языка, хоть и синтаксически похожи.

Для инициализации структуры таким образом как вы хотите в ваших вариантах, существует только 2 правильных:

1. Инициализация на месте:

```
struct private {
   /* поля.... */
};

/* Обратите внимание на тип структуры в скобках. */
struct private spriv = (struct private) { 0 }; /* заполнить все поля нулями */
```

2. *Агрегатная* инициализация, или так сказать инициализация исключительно указанных полей:

```
struct private spriv = (struct private) {
    .someField = 0,
    .someCopyOfField = 23,
    0 /* Остальные поля заполнить нулями */
};
```

Comment: В первом случае структура в скобках не нужна. Во втором - это не агрегатная инициализация, а инициализация через designated initializers. Причем фраза /* Остальные поля заполнить нулями */ тоже неверная.

Comment: @user7860670, да, там специально курсив. Про первый случай, я еще не видел что бы в си инициализировали структуры до их использования, мб так на автомате уже ставлю.

Answer (score 0):

Не позволяет такого синтаксис. Вы втором случае Вы пытаетесь инициализировать переменную в объявлении структуры. А оно так не работает. Нет в С конструкторов, поэтому и такая конструкция не работает. Даже так не работает

```
struct private {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
};
```

Но никто не мешает сделать так

```
struct private p = {0};
```

и все будет работать. Даже если есть вложенные структуры

в третьем случае Вы простите компилятор переменной присвоить ноль... а оно так не умеет. Самый надежный способ - позвать `memset`

```
memset(p, 0, sizeof(struct private));
```

Главное быть осторожным и не перепутать 2 и 3 параметр и не искать размер указателя, вместо размера структуры.

А первый пример работает, потому что там объявляется уже переменная (которая имеет место в памяти), а не структура (которая по факту чертеж памяти).

Comment: а если мне надо " = { 0 } " не всю структуру "приват" а только в  неё вложеную структуру?  и я пытался сделать это так же как в вашем втором примере (у меня это последний скрин) и оно все равно туже ошибку выдаёт.

Comment: При инициализации структуры `private p = { 0 };` сработает только с расширениями компилятора. Нужно указать тип в скобках перед инициализацией. `struct private p = ( struct private ) { 0 };`

Comment: @こきん, что-то ты не то говоришь...

Comment: @こきん Спасибо, указал преводимую структуру в () перед { 0 } и оно заработало

Comment: @Fat-Zer, все я правильно говорю, пойдите на линукс, включите `-pedantic-errors` и скомпилируйте код без указания типа структуры.

Comment: `private p = {0};`  - вот так давно уже работает. Да, если взять компилятор си 25 летней давности, то там и не такое не будет работать. А если взять хотя бы с11, то там даже структуры по значению можно возвращать из функции.

Comment: @こきん, [УМВР](https://godbolt.org/z/EvWWj7Pq6)... инициализация значением была всегда...

Comment: @KoVadim, только `struct private p...`, если `typedef` не сделан...

Comment: @Fat-Zer https://godbolt.org/z/EoaaPdPa5 нет.

Comment: да, я знаю. обычно я через typedef сразу структуры объявляю. Но я в основном на плюсах пишу

Comment: @こきん, баг в древней версии gcc — это странный аргумент... он жалуется не на синтаксис, а на то что инициализаторов меньше, чем членов структуры, а это явно разрешено и поведение описано стандартом **C89 3.5.7 Initialization**: *If there are fewer initializers in a list than there are members of an aggregate, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.*

Comment: @206435, в вопросе картинки вместо текста... в ответ на такоене хочется писать что-то содержательное...

Comment: А кто же этот минусатор?

Comment: @KoVadim чтобы узнать, кто минусует надо зайти не Мету.

Comment: да, там только общие ответы.

Comment: @KoVadim [вполне себе частные](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11694/%d0%98%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9#comment50296_11694).

Comment: м, будем надеяться, что больше не будет необоснованных минусов.